# Should the ordering of the summary page section be uniform across all sites?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I noticed a small quirk in the ordering of the summary tab of my own profile.
It's related to the left column where the `Answers`, `Questions`, `Accounts`, and `Active bounties` are listed.

I checked several pages an noticed that on [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com), [Photo](http://photography.stackexchange.com), [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com) and [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) the `Questions` section comes first (example from Apple.SE):

[image]

and on [Video](http://video.stackexchange.com), [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com) and [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) the `Answers` section comes first (example from Video.SE):
[image]

As mhlester pointed out in a comment, this is simply caused by the fact that I have asked more question than answers on the sites where the `Questions` section shows first and vice versa on the pages where `Answers` shows first.

Shouldn't the summary page be static, regardless of the question-to-answer ratio? I don't see why one would like to sort it like that.
Keeping the sections uniform allows me to go through all my user profiles and check for unaccepted answers for example, without having to "find" the section every time.

Comment: Whichever you have more of shows first. In the first group, you've asked more questions than answers. In the second group, you've answered more than you've asked.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. But wouldn't it be better keep the summary page static across the different pages? Edited question such that it is a discussion now.

Comment: I think it makes sense to show the most *relevant* information closest to the top. If someone is known for their questions, show their questions. If they're known for their answers, that's what I'd rather see. But all that said, [The profile page is getting a makeover](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover) so it's probably not worth changing now

Comment: The makeover makes my question quite irrelevant (based on the draft design).