# Profile image incorrectly marked as changed when editing other profile information

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture, profile-edit

I recently decided to remove some information from my profile so rather than make the same edit 42 times I decided to use the relatively new option of only copying the changes rather than copying everything. So I edited my Stack Overflow profile and then clicked the "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" button.

I did this on Thursday 23rd October, and didn't notice anything untoward. I wasn't online on Friday, but when I logged in this morning (Saturday 25th) I discovered that all my profile pictures had been changed to my Stack Overflow one. Where I can check<sup>*</sup> I can see that I have a "user switched profile image to imgur" entry at the time I made the change on Stack Overflow.

However, according to the information I can see on my Stack Overflow profile it *also* claims I changed my profile image on Thursday when I know I didn't. It seems that changing any other data on the profile also updates the image.

NOTE: When I copied the the other profile changes it only showed those changes I expected in the confirmation dialog.

* one of the perks of being a mod.

Comment: [Prepare for flood of upvotes in 3... 2... 1...](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/)

Answer (score 11):

For Winter Bash 2014, one of the [secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245397/1438) (Chameleon) was triggered by the  "user switched profile image" log entry. While tracking down why people were getting the hat without having changed their avatars, we discovered:

1. For people who use Gravatars, any profile edit triggers the log entry. Since a [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com/) is determined by hashing the email address, Gravatar users should only be logged as changing avatars when they update their email.
2. When a user has an "Uploaded picture" as their avatar, creating a linked account on another Stack Exchange site inserts a spurious log entry.

Your report seems to be something else again. Something added `?s=128&g=1` to the end of the Imgur URL. Perhaps it has something to do with preparing for the [new profile avatar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243844/1438)?

Comment: *Perhaps it has something to do with preparing for the new profile avatar size?* – It happened to me yesterday with a profile that I am quite certain to have updated after the general changes to the profile. (I do not use Gravatar either.)

Comment: I have noticed those "edited profile image" entries in my history after I made text-only changes to the "about me" block.  (I always make those only on single sites.)  I have not actually changed my profile image since the day I uploaded it or hooked it up to gravatar or whatever it was I did to get it, 5+ years ago.