# Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats

So far, I've unlocked one of the secret hats. I'm wondering what other secret hats are out there and how to earn them?

Comment: now the question is: do an unicorn hat exist?

Comment: also, if the count is correct, there must be one more secret hat around

Comment: @SPArchaeologist What count?

Comment: @Eran: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245213/2014-secret-hats-count

Comment: seems that based on core.js there are 8 secret hats. Which seems few to me, considering 3 star wars hats...

Comment: @SPArchaeologist There are 8 secret hats on this page, so it sounds like we have found all of them.

Comment: Will a list of the secret hats and their *exact* triggers be released *after* WB14 ends?

Comment: @Qix If they follow [last year's example](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/), then yes.

Comment: Gosh, there _really_ should be a [spoiler] system for SE... now I can never get the "Eureka" hat because I've seen the 'secrets' :cries:

Comment: @pepoluan There are spoilers. Head over to a Sandbox post and type in `!> something something something`.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secret

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat, aah, that's news to me! Unfortunately, can't unsee what I already have seen... :-/

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Now that Winter Bash 2014 is over, a wrap-up blog post has been written: [So long Winter Bash 2014](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/)

---

[image]

## Chameleon

Chameleon was supposed to be awarded to users when they change their avatar, but [a bug](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/242558/238586) triggered it in other situations, such as editing other profile fields or creating a linked account.

---

[image]

## Eureka!

Eureka! was manually awarded by the Stack Exchange staff to users who independently guessed how to get any secret hat (except Eureka! itself, [which first appeared during Winter Bash 2013](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/212799/254929)).

---

[image]

## Fascinating

Fascinating was earned by upvoting an accepted answer that had a score of at least 5.

---

[image]

## Fascinating, Ma'am

Fascinating, Ma'am was earned by upvoting a question that had a score of at least 25 and 10K views.

---

[image]

## Hairboat

Hairboat was earned by commenting on one of [abby hairboat](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/abby-hairboat)'s posts or replying to one of her comments.

---

[image]

## Time Lord

Time Lord was earned by editing five questions that were posted more than a year ago.

---

[image]

## Waffles

Waffles was earned by downvoting a question, editing it (approved suggested edits count) and then changing your downvote to an upvote.

---

[image]

## Warm Welcome

Warm Welcome was earned by upvoting any user's first post.

---

Please note that I (The Guy with The Elf Hat) did not figure out any of these hats by myself; I merely compiled all the information into one answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not related to award conditions, but worth noting that the comments on at least one of abby's recent posts are being cleaned up (presumably to avoid Abby Overflow).

Comment: Confirmed, editing About Me (only) triggered Chameleon for me.

Comment: I really appreciate you creating a canonical list, Guy with the Elf Hat!

Comment: I upvoted a few 25-score questions but didn't get *Fascinating, Ma'am*.

Comment: I find the “warm welcome” in a bad taste. A hat with a communist symbol that looks like it could possibly belong to a border patrol or gulag guard uniform? Shouldn’t such a thing rather be awarded for shooting new users’ posts on sight? Are we going to get hats with Hakenkreuze, too?

Comment: @Scimonster It worked for me on some sites but not others. I can't figure out what made it work or not. It doesn't seem to be related to voting on answers or to the age of the question.

Comment: We need to **SUGGEST EDIT**, right? If I am privileged to edit posts without them to be reviewed, that doesn't count, right?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ Count towards what?

Comment: Count as in that doesn't satisfy criteria for hat.

Comment: I have some form of proof that that closed questions don't count towards the time-lord hat, I would appreciate verification.

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ Which hat?

Comment: I got the Chameleon by changing my display name then changing it back again on the Tridion Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Does it bother anyone else that none of these look remotely like hats?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I'd say plenty of them look like hats. See  On The Road, Bugdroid, I Voted Today, Tam, o' Shanter, Kofia, Werewolf Hunter, Treasure Hunter, and Fear & Loathing.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to just the ones shown in this answer. I'm not complaining, mind you, I've worn a few of these "hats" already :)

Comment: Just leaving this here for reasons.

Comment: and I'm very interested in hearing more about your reasons.  How can I sign up for your newsletter?

Comment: @abbyhairboat Do you _want_ to get spammed with notifications?

Comment: Starting a new SE account by logging in with an existing SE account will trigger Chameleon. (for instance the meta account I created to post here)

Comment: @BenPlont Yes, I know. That's in the last bullet point in the Chameleon section of this answer.

Comment: @abbyhairboat you are really bad at playing hide and seek. You could have at least hid in [expatriates.se] meta or something.

Comment: Weird, I thought Fascinating was for upvoting a question, comment and answer on the same page. I guess those times I did that I must have just happened to vote upvoted accepted answers. Shame, I kind of liked what I thought it was!

Comment: @abbyhairboat:  Is there a more natural way to go about that hat?  You don't lurk anywhere near enough to Workplace for me to not have to find you on MSE (and I rather like Workplace.SE)... :(

Comment: Does my logic on Chameleon seem pretty on point?

Comment: I just got a "Warm Welcome" for upvoting a 2-year-old post on StackOverflow ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220676/what-are-zombies-and-what-causes-them-are-there-zombie-processes-and-zombie-obj?rq=1))

Comment: Arguably useful information: Fascinating is Spock (obviously). Fascinating, Ma'am appears to be Tuvok. "Ma'am" because he would be saying it to Janeway, I suppose.

Comment: Can confirm Chameleon worked for me

Comment: @Chenmunka Interesting . . . I tried several questions on Blender.SE (3D application) and I did not get the hat. So I decided to try it again, and after making sure it fit the criteria, I got it within a few minutes.

Comment: So far everything seems correct, but for the Time Lord hat, how did you find old questions?

Comment: @PaulG http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?page=1389&pagesize=50&sort=newest

Comment: @Sompuperoo Of course it's a real separate hat!

Comment: @Sompuperoo You already got it. It's a weird hat in that it's automatically worn as soon as you earn it. However, because it's a _secret_ secret hat, it doesn't show up in the hat list.

Comment: For Praying Mantis... I ___still___ cannot tell whether it actually exists, or is just the Chameleon.

Comment: Hm, I've also been wearing the Chameleon hat upside down for quite a while and I see no separate hat. If it doesn't count in the hatcount, why is there a separate hat name for it? :/

Comment: By the way, I guess the @abbyhairboat hat is unachievable  on Math.StackExchange?

Comment: I just upvoted the 1st answer on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379927/a-simple-3rd-grade-problem-or-is-it. Why didn't I get the fascinating hat?

Comment: @user45195 You did.

Comment: Wish I could get the @abbyhairboat hat on Academia!

Comment: Chameleon has to do with having multiple accounts, maybe partaking in activity on more than one site/being a trusted user.

Comment: Can confirm that joining a site gives you a hat, happened to my when trying to join this site

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat Yes, I noticed. I had to log out and log in again to receive it, though.

Comment: I got the ***Chameleon*** hat by visiting Stack Overflow via a proxy (Tor Browser- was having cache issues).

Comment: @Ahaan If you're not privy yet, the Praying Mantis "hat" is a joke. The Chameleon hat looks like a bug upside-down, but you don't actually earn a new hat for it.

Comment: @Kevin I see; thanks for the response! Still wondering about the Chameleon hat. It seems I can't get it on Math.StackExchange even though someone who seems like he shouldn't have gotten it actually got it. :/

Comment: Chameleon can also be got by just changing the profile pic (to an actual face that can wear hats). But I got my favourite hat now, だってばよ！

Comment: Hm, the eureka description is a bit fuzzy... I mean, I just got the chameleon, thought "oh, it must have been the new site I joined; hm, the name makes sense for changing 'what you are' so changing other things in your profile should work too" so I essentially guessed what one can get it for, but so far no Eureka hat. So there must be more to it than just guessing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245712/238586

Comment: @abbyhairboat yay for hats.

Comment: @abbyhairboat - is this true?

Comment: @abbyhairboat Just leaving *this* here for reasons

Comment: For me it feels like there's no per-user setting for obtaining Chameleon hat, on the contrary - looks like this is server-wide setting, which changes over time. My observation for this is that I spent several minutes, trying and changing fields in my profile without luck. I also tried to register account as it suggested , but also to no avail. At last I did update all the fields and a picture over all of my profiles, which resulted in obtaining hat from all of the sites. Some time later I did register another account and got a hat again. So I believe it's time dependent, not user.

Comment: @abbyhairboat This is a comment.

Comment: @abbyhairboat You poor thing, your inbox must be overflowing! Fancy joining up to [Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com)? ;-)

Comment: I just wanted to tell you guys that I got the chameleon without changing my profile, other than changing a hat. I did not change the profile picture, itself.

Comment: So is it impossible to get Time Lord on betas less than a year old?

Comment: @randal'thor Assuming the time limit is one year, yes.

Comment: @cybermonkey I was using a proxy too when I bagged the Chameleon iirc. Hrm...  (Pretty sure I also answered and had an answer accepted on the site where I was proxying.)

Comment: Argh. Danged 5-min limit. New in bold: I also **created an account**, answered, and had that **answer voted up** and accepted on the site where I was proxying, fwiw. I should also add I'm loving my mantis hat. Reminds me of the [Vrusk](http://starfrontiers.wikia.com/wiki/Vrusk).

Comment: @ruffin Simply creating an account is enough to get you the hat

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246612/238586) discussion.

Answer (score 28):

[image]

<strike>I've noticed a mod with this hat and he recently did a roll back on a question. Seems like an appropriate action for a time lord.It seems like edits to old questions instead of rollback based on comments below, but how old is TBD.</strike>

[See Martijn Pieters's answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245270/236364)

Comment: Rollback on a question as a non-mod is not enough.

Comment: can't be mod only. Look here. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2221895/don-chakkappan

Comment: Answering a _old_ question doesn't get you a tardis, either

Comment: Let's put that to the test, @MartijnPieters :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No luck so far...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh, that edit was on my own old post

Comment: @Cerbrus: Oh, you sly wolf, who did you get to upvote that post?

Comment: Who loves hats more than any of us? Gaben.

Comment: I edited an old post of mine and it was updated: no tardis :(

Comment: @fredley I upvoted your edited question on Arqade to see if it would make a difference. Looks like you got the hat, so maybe it did :)

Comment: @Eran Maybe it was the upvote that made the difference! Still no waffle though... :(

Comment: How old has to be the post?

Comment: I edited very old question (not mine) and within 5 minutes, I got this hat. may be 3 years.