# 2014 Secret hats: count?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014, winter-bash, secret-hats

Is it known how many secret hats exist in this winter bash? What about last year?

Also, are hats being added during the event? Should the Stack Exchange team come up with new ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is known how many secret hats there are this year – pretty much any employee has access to that information.

[Winter Bash 2013 had 10 secret hats.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/)

All hat orders are finalized before Winter Bash begins. Due to the lead time required in hat manufacturing, we're unable to product new hats once the event begins. New ideas might be saved to jumpstart the trends of next season.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. Since it's technically a more accurate answer to my question, I'll "Accept" it.

Comment: ... :P nice one Laura, but I think he meant "It is know to the community". And btw, where is the unicorn? SE Chart of Constitution clearly states that "each event shall contain an unicorn reference". You forgot the hat ;_;

Answer (score 22):

Based on core.js, it seems that there are 30 standard hats and 8 secret ones. This is assuming hichris123's deductions were correct.

Comment: That's quite the assumption there ... :p