# Polite request for more secret hats plZ

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats

I don't know how many secret hats currently exist. Probably at least 7. But whatever the number is, please double it! I want more secret hats!

Comment: based on core.js the number is 8. And the Twilight hat is nowhere to be found, only one secret hat remaining

Comment: @SPArchaeologist There's still a chance, don't lose hope!

Comment: Well, I can just use her for an avatar, at least for the holyday period

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: #8 is called HairBoat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are increasing hats, we might as well go up to 64, right?

So I vote for 8 times :-)

Answer (score 10):

I agree! I want secret hats too! Please triple it!

Answer (score 7):

I'm all for increasing the secret hats. But don't forgot about regular hats! There's 30 non-secret regular hats I see. While were at it, lets double that too!

Comment: Yes, we should have an incredible lots of hats so we will never run out of things to do for Christmas. Stack Exchange all day long!

Comment: @Unihedro You have like 16 hats in 1 day. So it would only take about between 6-8 days to get them all if we doubled!

Comment: 22 hats, so that'd be 3 days :3

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, [there are thought to be 8 secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245213/2014-secret-hats-count).

Go, hunt for those hats, and maybe even get yourself a "Eureka", if you're lucky!

Still, we need more hats. At least 4 times the current amount.