# Hints for Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats

I've seen [the other question about a list of secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170/180276), but I don't want to spoil the fun. I still want fancy sekrit hats, though!

What hints do you have for earning some of these secret hats? One hat per answer, please, and duplicate answers are okay if you have more hints to add.

Comment: want picture of the hat / hat name or nothing?

Comment: @SPArchaeoligist A picture if you want, but it doesn't really matter (I'm on mobile, so I can't add pictures).

Comment: Isn't it an exact duplicate ? The other question has all the hints you want.

Comment: @optimizer The other one just says exactly how to get it.

Answer (score 12):

## Chameleon

> You have to *blend in* to the site to earn this.

> Perhaps you could *change* something about yourself.

> What represents you on a Stack Exchange site?

> It's your profile.

> How can you make your profile blend in?

> To blend in, your profile must change. And how do you do that?

Answer (score 8):

**Time Lord**

> Back and forth in time I go
>  Fixing stuff wherever it needs to

Answer (score 7):

## Warm Welcome

> One of the nicest ways to welcome a new member into a stack exchange site.

an alternative hint :

> Something you never do in the first posts queue.

Comment: *goes to vote-to-close newbie questions*

Comment: @Bart or for NAA / spam flags for answers.

Answer (score 5):

## Fascinating

> What do you do on Stack Exchange when you find something *fascinating*?

> It's one of the first privileges you unlock.

> Okay, now **accept** (hint, hint) the fact that you'll have to earn this hat with posts that are marked as such.

> The post must be considered fascinating by others, as well.

> Hence, the hat has something to do with upvoted accepted answers.

Answer (score 4):

## Hairboat

> [hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/abby-hairboat)

Answer (score 3):

## Waffle

> Well, do you or don't you like it?

> It's not side-to-side.

> You're not really looking for an answer...

> Maybe you'd think more of it if you contributed a little...

> Change your mind?

Answer (score 2):

## Eureka (probably can't be obtained anymore)

> Seems you discovered something, haven't you?

> And you were the first one, too.

> You got your brevet registered, no one can claim he discovered it before.

> So now you just have to wait for the print to give you glory.

Answer (score 2):

## Fascinating, Ma'am

> The names are similar, are they?

> Both vulcanian, they are almost the same

> Question, answers, both are post right?

> One for each, no one left out