# Is wearing/changing hat considered as changing profile picture?

Tags: support, profile-picture, winter-bash-2014

I know. I know. I know it's very easy to change a profile picture, but I'm still asking this as this question is related to a secret hat called Chameleon and to earn this hat you just need to change your profile picture. So is wearing/changing hat considered as changing profile picture?

Comment: BTW asking people not to downvote is a downvote magnet. Instead, point out that you had trouble trying to change your profile picture.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, changing your hat doesn't count for getting the Chameleon badge. I changed my hats a few times without unlocking Chameleon.

Also, you don't necessarily have to change your profile picture - changing anything in the "About me" section does the trick, according to the answers on [Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170/168333).

**EDIT**: Updating my own "About me" didn't unlock it, but changing my profile picture to Gravatar unlocked in within 2 minutes. Now wearing it as proof.

Comment: Quote: **changing anything in the "About me" section does the trick.** You can?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I just did - go to your personal page and click "edit". Is there some reason you can't do this? Maybe a browser issue?

Comment: Pretty much a browser issue. Tried it on a different computer with my other account and it worked.

Comment: I earned it by logging into a new SE site for the first time.