# Mouse over effect ! how to do it?

Tags: discussion

**Check this [Mouse over effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats/245835#245835)**  within blockquote

I checked the [revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/245835/revisions) for mouse over effect but no luck on it. how to do it? I'm not sure this is a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer a mouse-over effect, but rather a big empty box you have to click on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's a feature that's useful for puzzling sites, where you don't want to give away spoilers to people who want to figure answers out for themselves.

The syntax is `>!` at the beginning of a line.

> Like this!

You can click "edit" on a post to view the Markdown that was used to create it.

Blockquotes, as I'm sure you know, simply don't have the exclamation mark.

> Tada!