# When will the "reloaded" profile be back?

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page

Some time earlier, a new [profile page was announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover-part-one). And, I remember, it was great.

Where is it now?  Why does going to https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/13249/nick-craver lead to a 404 error? When will it be back?

Comment: It can't be a bug since the new design was never released. It's just a nice-to-have feature they added for a short while, and removed when it became irrelevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

6-8 weeks.

We are working on changes to this page, following the community feedback given on the original design.

The changes are still being iterated on, but we are in a good place now to preview internally, then bring out to the community.

Comment: [status-completed] or you'll remove it again later?

Comment: @nicael - we don't status-complete discussions... we do bugs and feature requests ;)