# When will the new profile page be released, network-wide?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

We've had the preview for the new profile for a while, and I'm curious as to when it's planned for release.

I've seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243680/175002) discussion, but the 8 weeks estimate is now out....by a lot.

The last estimate I saw was [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features#comment816600_249951). That put us to mid-March.

Do we know when it's coming out? I know there're a few issues still, but most of the [active issues raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features?answertab=active#tab-top) are completed<sup>1</sup>.

If we don't know, that's also fine. I'm not criticising, just anxiously awaiting this present you guys are delivering.

<sup>1: that might be an artifact of them being edited with the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)/[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).</sup>

Comment: Oh, the first one you pointed is quite unrelated; I asked it when this *new* page was *old*; 70% redesigned since.

Comment: 6-8 weeks. Really. :-D

Comment: ...[another reason](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdn3O.png) why a make-over should roll out.

Answer (score 1):

We're half done:

[Two new user pages. One new stat. This one’s big.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1)

Comment: Is there any news about when the rst of the pages will get the new layout?

Comment: @raidri none so far..