# why are the best questions the ones which have been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I frequently come across a really useful answer on StackOverflow which has been closed because it doesn't match the Q&A format.

Examples include 
[JPA Implementations - Which one is the best to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576659), 
[How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369), 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080499/are-weekly-status-meetings-necessary ,
[What's Up with Logging in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354837/whats-up-with-logging-in-java)
and there are others.

Where should this information be exchanged if it's not on stackoverflow?

It seems the moderators are often somewhat overzealous...

---edit

When I say best, I mean they are informative and useful for someone who's looking for an answer to them.  Even if they do become a bit of a discussion, I *value* other people's opinions on the relative merits of the different JPA frameworks.  I come here looking to choose one and the answer helps me.  So what if it's not a definitive answer?

---edit

I don't care how popular a question is, nor how interesting it is.  Users are interested in stuff that's *useful* to them.  Plenty of those were useful (as judged by the upvotes on the answers: 'This answer is useful'), but closed because they didn't have a definitive answer, as far as I can tell.

---edit

Seems I'm not the first person to think this: there are various similar questions to mine like this one: [Is there a problem with Stack Overflow when extremely useful, massively upvoted/favorited questions get closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92980)

In it the user lists lots of other useful questions which have been closed:

- [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid
- [What are your favorite extension methods for C#? (codeplex.com/extensionoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow)
- [jQuery Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs
- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
- [Hidden Features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries
- [Exploitable PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions)
- [Hidden Features of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript)
- [What should every JavaScript programmer know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628672/what-should-every-javascript-programmer-know)
- [What are best practices that you use when writing Objective-C and Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa)
- [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)
- [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)
- [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

So isn't there a place on stackoverflow for these questions?  A discussion section, maybe?