# Request for tool recommendations are off-topic, but

Tags: discussion, off-topic

...but this question: [What are your favorite general purpose Django apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431167/535871) is still actively collecting answers; has received comments like *"This is a spectacularly useful thread. Thanks!"*; has not received even a single close vote; yet clearly flies in the face of [the criteria for on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I think that this particular thread helps a lot of people in the community; I would definitely not want it to be closed. However, I think that if this exact question were asked today (instead of 4 years ago), it would be closed in short order.

I understand perfectly well why this kind of question often leads to undesirable opinion-mongering. However, considering how useful this particular thread itself is, would there be some value in revising the criteria for what can be asked? Perhaps a way could be found to make room for this kind of thread when it actually is a valuable resource for the community? (Note that the [help page for programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) directs that community to SO for questions about programming tools. There appears to be no place in the StackExchange network for this kind of thread.)

Comment: Waaaiiit for it...

Comment: Recursion, *n.*: See *recursion*

Comment: Related (and recent): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200122/why-are-the-best-questions-the-ones-which-have-been-closed

Comment: I fear if you didn't want it closed mentioning it here was a bad plan, also Programmers was originally envisioned to include these sort of things, see [this excellent answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200122/why-are-the-best-questions-the-ones-which-have-been-closed/200144#200144) on how that went

Comment: And done.  Thanks for bringing that close worthy question to our attention.

Comment: Is it too much to migrate to the [tag-info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/django/info)?

Comment: Incidentally, Vincent perfectly showed why these questions aren't great "As I see, this question still get visits. But please note it's quite outdated. Many, many nice apps appeared since then. It's worth re-asking the same question today". Ah Vincent, so wise, where are you now

Comment: This type of question isn't as good a fit for our model as more practical ones are. And you're right in pointing out that SO has made these questions off-topic. But they are welcome, [in highly limited and controlled ways on other sites](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/got-any-tips-or-tricks-for-terminal-in-mac-os-x). Which is good, when it fits the community, as *less factual than our other questions* is okay if you're creating something *more useful than the alternatives*, as long as it isn't chasing off your experts.

Comment: There's a clear difference between questions about programming tools ("AV when compiling my project in VS 2012?") and asking for recommendations for a tool/library ("What are the best plug-ins for this IDE?"). The first asks about a specific problem that is being experienced, and may be of general use later to someone. The second asks for opinion, speculation, and links that may change/projects or products that might disappear tomorrow, begs for spam and product advertisements ("Our product/project..."), and has no specific problem to solve. They're hardly the same thing at all.