# What about those subjective questions? Is there a place for them?

Tags: discussion

For me at least, one of the best things about SO is the fact that I can find general questions answered by many different people, often with specific reasoning, but also often with subjective assessments.

Recently, however, I've noticed that the majority of pages I find -- and in particular, the most useful of those pages, the ones like this (just a random example, I could find much better):

[Logging best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576185/logging-best-practices)

Are closed as "not constructive", despite the hundreds of people who certainly found the information *useful*. I admit I don't understand the difference between "constructive" and "useful" either.

I believe this is a duplicate of other questions, like this:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180767/new-stackexchange-discussion-site-for-not-constructive-questions

But I can't see them.

Is all this just a consequence of not being able to scale and take the additional load that conversations will generate, or ... what?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with load. SO isn't a forum, it's a question and answer site.

Comment: These sort of questions which generate discussion/opinion rather than definite answers drive off experts, see [the very good answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200122/why-are-the-best-questions-the-ones-which-have-been-closed/200144#200144) in the quoted duplicate

Comment: @RichardTingle That answer is referring to "Not Programming Related" questions. I'm not asking why polls about the most annoying way someone's messed up code aren't allowed. I'm asking why questions that fit "subjective" criteria are all (as far as I can tell) getting closed--does the Logging Best Practices link above fail the 6 rules? http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice

Comment: Polls in general aren't really a great fit for the Q&A format. All answers to that question would be equally valid. Real polling software would be much much better for that

Answer (score 6):

> Is all this just a consequence of not being able to scale and take the additional load that conversations will generate, or ... what?

In a sense, yes.

But not load on the servers or the network. Rather, strain on the folks actually here looking to provide or receive answers to programming questions.

A small group of people can pretty much do whatever they want, because they can *know* what they want - but as the community grows, this becomes harder and harder to accomplish. A straw-poll with 5-10-30 responses is still something that an interested reader can use - but no one with a real problem to solve wants to sit down and read pages and pages of replies in order to get an answer. The voting system breaks down, the reputation system breaks down, the big hope for the platform - high signal, low noise - disappears.

So how to prevent this? Well, disallow the sorts of questions that encourage it, and encourage questions that target experts instead of "everyone":

- Don't ask what everyone uses; describe your scenario and ask what *you* should use.
- Don't ask what everyone thinks is best; ask what would be ideal *for your needs*.
- Don't ask for problems everyone has encountered; describe a problem *you've* encountered and ask how to solve it.
- ...

Yes, this is harder, because you actually have to think about your problem and communicate it to others. But it also makes it much easier to stay focused on what this site was created to build: a repository of great answers to programming problems.

Comment: But... that *was* a great answer :( I really wish that SO would seriously look into providing a place for this content to go, rather than (apparently) washing their/your hands of it.

Comment: It's not *gone*, Benjol. None of the answers there had been touched in 2.5 years, so I doubt it's missing out on much. The problem with creating a site for these is that for all of the lip-service, for all of the long, well-researched answers on such questions... There are 10x as many questions that never got more than a one-liner, and *mostly* just get spam. The first step on such a site would be to formulate rules that would somehow disallow this - and that first step's a doozy.

Comment: It's not gone yet. I could handle your locking it, but now there have been votes to close, and (AFAIC) that's the first step on the way to deletion (or in any case, it seems totally superfluous coming on the top of a lock). The first step would be quite easy, to my mind: votes.

Comment: Historical Lock is pretty final, @Benjol - no more voting or flagging. Those votes predate the lock.