# Why one shouldn't ask a question of Superuser in StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

I had a problem related to Drive partitioning i asked it on superuser here is the link [Assigning drive letter to free space failed due to error](https://superuser.com/questions/659164/i-want-to-assign-drive-letter-to-free-space-but-failed-due-to-error)

i was not getting quick response so, i decided to ask the same question on stackoverflow, and eventually i was downvoted and question held as off-topic.

My concern is, if there are knowledgeable persons on stackoverflow who are not on superuser, then they should help me. i think there should be some way to allow these activities without downvoting the user.

Comment: If there weren't limits on topic, it would just be answers.yahoo.com

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). The reason shown on the downvote tooltip also applies: "this question does not show any research effort." Just reading [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) answers your question.

Comment: It's good that you ask the question here, but don't ask it as a feature-request. You are actually  asking "as a feature-request" that SE sites should not be specific!

Comment: well i will be careful in future..

Comment: Explanation of 90% of downvotes; "then they **should** help me"

Comment: why i am not able to close or delete this question?? i can't see myself downvoted very minute.

Comment: I am afraid that questions with upvoted answers cannot be deleted because that would delete the answer as well

Comment: An ability to ask any question subject regardless of the Stack site is completely against the entire structure of the Stack sites, & is why you got many downvotes on this question (ie people *disagree*) regardless of it being a feature request or not. The point of having specific sites is to gather experts together in a particular subject, so you actually benefit more by it being the way it is now, and would be less likely to get a [decent] answer if Stack sites were all just, well, forums or yahoo answers.

Comment: Also, wanting to delete your question because you got down voted a lot goes against the grain. You asked a question, whether valid or popular or not, people have taken their own personal time to give you answers, and to just want to wipe all that away is bad sport. Patience is the state of endurance under difficult circumstances, which can mean persevering in the face of delay or provocation without acting on annoyance/anger in a negative way. Patience is the level of endurance one can take before negativity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know it seems harsh to have these very strict rules, however they are there to allow the site to exist at all. If any and all questions were accepted then it would be great for the first person but soon the experts would be driven out and there would be no one left to answer even your on topic questions.

An example of what happened with relaxed (not removed) rules was explored in (what later became) programmers where subjective questions were allowed. In short the noise kept people away and almost killed the site before the rules were tightened up. This is explored in detail in this answer; [why are the best questions the ones which have been closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200122/why-are-the-best-questions-the-ones-which-have-been-closed/200144#200144)

Not to mention that the people most likely to be able to answer your question are the people who are on the site where your question is on topic; to post elsewhere is to waste everyone's time.

Ultimately there are many many websites where you could ask your question with far reduced rules; you decided to use stack overflow **because** the rules here have allowed this to be one of the best programming Q&A sites.

Comment: this answer seems to be the best so far :)

Answer (score 33):

For the same reason that you don't ask a question about cooking on the bicycles site, or a question about programming on the cooking site.

If you let people ask about *anything*, you get [this](http://answers.yahoo.com).

> but if you know about cooking, wouldn't you tell me on bicycle site???

No, because people go to a bicycles site to ask and answer about **bicycles!** If there was a random cooking question on there, then everyone would start asking about random topics and it would just me chaos.

[image: example]

> becuz, f i can't get my answers on one site then should i wait and die for answers or should i go and ask on other sites where i think i can get help

That's like saying a painter should do your brain transplant if a doctor is not available. Programmers are software people; most of us are pretty clueless about hardware `:)`

The painter would probably kill you in the process. Anyway, it's not as if you're going to die if you don't get an answer ***right now*** ah҉h͠hh h͘͞ę̴lp͞͏ ͘m͜͠e I *ne***e`d`** *a**n** a*`ns`**we***r* I'm̪ ̧͍̯̫ͅg̬͎͡oí̠̤͈n͇͔̙̘g̢͕̠̟̼͉͕ ̹̮̯̙͖̘to͇̠̝͇̗̟ ̙̼̳**D͍̥͓̱̩I͙̮E̤̞̦̞̼**

Comment: but if you know about cooking, wouldn't you tell me on bicycle site???

Comment: No. I'd say "maybe later, currently I'm working on my bicyle"

Comment: well that answer sounds killing "Humanity" as well "Unconditional helping nature"

Comment: Btw, many wouldn't visit this site if everything you see is useless crap for me (like gardening. I don't have a garden.).

Comment: So much for cooking *on* a bicycle...

Comment: LOLzzz i feel like i am awakened now, as i see people around me so arrogant and rude, without any kind of helping nature. thanx to this site...

Comment: "Programmer on a boat". @RoshanJha Translate my comment as "no, I'm currently not visiting [cooking.SE], but I might answer your question when I visit it."

Comment: @RoshanJha Yeah, how dare we not give you everything that you want in exchange for you doing nothing in return.  We should go out of our way to give you everything that you want just because it's you that wants it.

Comment: if a person is dying, and you can save him. but you don't know where he is. and if i tell you look there he is, now will you let him die???

Comment: @RoshanJha No, but how does that have anything to do with this topic?

Comment: becuz, f i can't get my answers on one site then should i wait and die for answers or should i go and ask on other sites where i think i can get help

Comment: @RoshanJha: In a way, proposing a feature request is different from just asking for help.  On Meta, a question tagged as a feature request *will* get downvoted if others disagree with it.

Comment: `if i can't get my answers on one site then should i wait and die` You don't think that's a bit of an overstatement?

Comment: @RoshanJha That's like saying a painter should do your brain transplant if a doctor is not available.

Comment: Make sure you hit him in the ass on his way out.

Comment: Clearly, we should add a disclaimer to all Stack Exchange sites: "If you are currently dying, please hang up and dial 911."

Comment: why not a painter?? if i am going to die without transplant, then its better to opt for painter if there is no doctor

Comment: @RoshanJha Not sure if serious, or just trolling...

Comment: @RoshanJha The painter would probably kill you in the process. Anyway, it's not as if you're going to die if you don't get an answer ***right now*** **ahhhh help me** ***I NEED AN ANSWER*** *I'm going to **DIE***

Comment: certainly not, but you should understand the gravity of what i am saying

Comment: Yeah, I'm already falling down to *insert random place*.

Comment: @RoshanJha: Indeed.  Post a question in the appropriate place and *wait* for an answer.  Chances are, you won't be downvoted for that (unless you're still lacking research).

Comment: thinking about going to a restaurant and ask "I'd like to buy a bicycle"

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with programming. The questions posted on the websites should be usefull for people in the future looking for answers. People should know what stackoverflow is about before they search / ask a question and if they do know they wont be searching your question on stackoverflow.

If you could just post all kind of questions on stackoverflow which has nothing to do with programming, it would be a chaos.