# Why does my question about installing Trac have a close vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, question-quality

At the risk of attracting more "close" votes on my question, I'm just trying to find out what about [this specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729481/installing-trac-trac-requires-python-2-5-or-later) warrants it being closed.

The question was posted a few minutes ago, and just received an inexplicable "close" vote with no comment. The question is about a specific problem, includes actions leading to the problem, and identifies a possible solution.  The question itself asks whether the proposed solution is the correct one.

How could I rewrite the question to avoid having users vote to close it?

Comment: the close vote says offtopic and suggest serverfault.com

Comment: OK thanks - I wasn't sure where to see vote details.

Comment: Why isn't this question closed and moved?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212738/python-2-6-bindings-for-svn-1-6-6

Comment: Because the mere existence of a rule or guideline does not automatically result in its immediate universal enforcement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is about a specific problem, includes actions leading to the problem, and identifies a possible solution. The question itself asks whether the proposed solution is the correct one.

All true, except it's not a programming problem. You could also ask a very specific problem about bike maintenance that identifies a possible solution, but it wouldn't be on-topic on SO either

SO's position on generic questions about tools used by programmers tends to be [fuzzy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113087/software-tools-in-faq-is-too-hazy), so I don't vote on those questions, but I assume the person who did vote to close was telling you to go to somewhere like [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Is there a way to request a question be moved to another Stack Network site?  Would I be penalized for reposting the same question on Unix/Linux?

Comment: @acoder: Try flagging it for mod attention.

Comment: @acoder Well, it'll get moved automatically if enough people vote to migrate it (which is part of off-topic), but you can [flag for mod attention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review) and ask them to move it. Don't repost it, it'll still be on SO then

Comment: Thanks, I've flagged it myself.   Could you assist by flagging for migration?

Comment: If the question is closed does it permanently die?

Comment: @acoder I don't know what you mean by "die", but [this happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

Comment: Ok question was migrated.

Comment: What confuses me is that tags on stack overflow (including  easy_install ) that have nothing to do with development, and should be on unix/linux, are not on unix/linux.