# If this question is off topic, where would it be on topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic

Wanting to debug on JSfiddle and answer a question involving audio, I asked this question

https://stackoverflow.com/q/13666715/295783

It was closed

**UPDATE:** It is open again.

**UPDATE:** It is closed again! This is getting downright silly!

I do not get it. I am close to 20K rep at SO and I have voted close (and reopen after editing) quite a few questions. I still do not get it. I can move it to Meta if that would be more appropriate.

According to me, the question asks for a way to link to public domain ogg, m4a or a site to be used in a jsfiddle, to test questions that involve audio.

I strongly believe it fits FAQ 3:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

Perhaps it is not yet commonly used by programmers if it does not exist or no one knows it exists. But that does not mean it is not useful for programmers at SO and could become commonly used. JSFiddle was not commonly used until it was discovered.

Perhaps there is room for a question that helps a SO user help other SO users regardless of the vagueness of the faq?

Comment: if you're on a mac, you can use `say -o file.m4a lorem ipsum text` to create your own, if you only need one file

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I have changed the question title and added more justification

Comment: Stop the discussion? Sure. You ask if the question is on-topic for SO. No, it isn't. It's not-constructive and not covered by the FAQ entry you quote. Where is it on-topic? Nowhere to the best of my knowledge. If you want to leave it there, fair enough.

Comment: You know what I mean, Bart.

Comment: You just want to seemingly ignore everything explained you you here and have your question reopened to be given a chance. I don't think that should happen precisely because of all the reasons given to you here.

Comment: Sitting on the fence here, but to be honest even if your question will be reopened, it will just be closed again sooner or later, most likely sooner by a mod now that it got so much attention. My best advice is to accept the sour pill and move on. :)

Comment: Thanks @ShaWizDowArd - Bart seemingly ignores the spirit of the question and insists that it should be closed, disregarding it is is a genuine need and asked by someone who wants to help others at SO. Oh well. Not the first time I disagree with the upholding of some rule just to uphold the rule.

Comment: First of all this is not a personal thing. This is not me vs. you. Second, rules are in place for a reason. If we go the whole "spirit of the question route", well, hang around on Meta for a while to see all the crap that will come this way. Take your question to chat if you must. And once you find something, start using it. People will most likely be quick to pick it up if useful.

Comment: Useful does not always means it fits. Something might be ultra good and super useful, yet not fitting for Stack Overflow. For good and for bad, it will accept only certain questions and while I'm not sure that's the way to keep the place thriving, I don't think it will change any time soon. The "software tools" area is a gray zone as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 18):

> I strongly believe it fits FAQ 3:
>
> software tools commonly used by programmers

Your question is a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). It's a recommendation question.

This clause of the FAQ is not intended to let you ask "give me a tool that does X" questions. It's for "I'm using tool X and it's not working in this way that I expect it to" question.

Comment: Exactly. And just as stating "no endless discussion or debate please" doesn't make a question constructive, asking for "commonly used tools" doesn't make it in line with the quoted FAQ entry.

Comment: Sheez. Getting quite tired here. I repeat: I am trying to help people and need a tool to help people but the other people on the site where I try to help people are beating me over the head with something more non-constructive than my question!

Comment: @mplungjan: You don't really get this. SO has specific requirements for questions on this site. Your question doesn't meet those requirements. Therefore, it was closed. It doesn't matter if that question might be helpful to someone; if it doesn't meet the requirements we set down, it gets closed. We don't allow shopping questions, so your shopping question was closed.

Comment: Last comment. I recognise shopping questions. This is not one of them. End of story. I see I do not have a chance here, so let's just leave some crappier questions on SO and delete a real request from a someone who after a long time at SO still does not get it. Thanks for the cooperation.

Answer (score 13):

Better in a chat room.

Not for Meta. Not even for Web Applications.

The question is asking for a website or external resource and falls into the kind that fit the "Has anyone seen my keys?" and "What mechanic should I go to?" format.

They are questions better for a search engine or directory lookup. Goes along the lines of a product recommendation.

If you had a question about working with such a web service's API, that would be on topic.

Comment: i agree that maybe the subject was off topic, but the reasons you give are not fair. he is not looking for a product *recommendation*-- he's trying to find *any* site that fits this criterion, if one exists. this is very much objective and answerable. re: looking on google... if a 20k user makes a post, i think it's implied that he already tried and turned up nothing

Comment: Reputation doesn't imply anything other than having posts that have been well upvoted

Comment: Yes I looked. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: @random do you seriously think there's no correlation between reputation and quality of posting? *really*? if it were true that you could post over 1,000 answers and gain over 18k rep without learning how to formulate a good question/answer, this site would absolutely not function.

Comment: Quality of the question isn't under review here, but whether or not it's on topic. Reputation does not signal that the user definitely knows what is and isn't on topic @jef

Comment: i think you missed the part of my comment where i agreed the subject was off topic...

Comment: @Jeff While the question may be "objective and answerable" using that phrasing, it would result in a "list of things" and none of them could ever be objectively any better than any others, thus making it still fall into the "not constructive" bucket, and also "too localized" (there's often an overlap between those two).

Answer (score 9):

Well, let's look at the Stack Overflow FAQ:

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

> • a specific programming problem
>   • a software algorithm
>   • software tools commonly used by programmers
>   • practical, answerable problems that are *unique* to the programming profession

Do you honestly feel that your question met any of those criteria? I don't.

Comment: So questions have to fit ALL of those? Did you see my highlight in my post? the one about point 3 which I think fits my question?

Comment: @mplungjan One of the key terms in point #3 of FAQ is **commonly used**. Since the post does not mention any tool (so the community can not figure out if it is a commonly used tool or not) thus the post does not fit point #3 either hence off-topic.

Comment: I have changed the question to ask for a COMMONLY USED TOOL !!!

Comment: That doesn't really improve the question one bit imho. If it's not off-topic it's at least not-constructive. P.s. you might want to remove the capitals. It's all a bit shouty.

Comment: @mplungjan - You are supposed to ask questions about problems encountered when using the tools, not where to find tools.

Comment: [I'll just leave this here for reference purposes...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113087/software-tools-in-faq-is-too-hazy).

Answer (score 6):

Since we're quoting the FAQ here, I'd like to quote this part:

> ... avoid asking subjective questions where ...
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

That's essentially what your question is asking: "What's your favorite tool to test audio in jsfiddle?" You don't state it as such, but it has the same essential characteristic: All answers will be equally valid. It's not constructive. If there were 50 such tools, there could very well be 50 different answers, and none would be more right or wrong than another. You'd have to choose based purely on your opinion. Just because you don't know of any answers already doesn't make the question any more constructive.

Now, to answer your actual meta question of "Where is this on-topic?" I don't think there's any SE site where this question would be on topic. But off the top of my head, some good places where it would be on topic include:

- Stackoverflow chat.
- Tech or power user forums (and SE sites are not forums).

Comment: I completely DISAGREE. I am not asking for a favourite, I am asking for ANY since I could not find even one!

Comment: @mplungjan, exactly: you are asking for *ANY*. That's a recipe for not constructive.

Comment: facepalm - there is no What is your favorite and no Any in my question anymore! "How to test audio" "Is there a similar site or method for testing audio?" Anyway. Open again

Comment: The problem with your question (and where it becomes "not-constructive") is that you are asking whether or not there are any sites out there which fit certain criteria. This is asking for a recommendation and has the potential to turn into a list of answers any one not more or less correct than the other. This falls under the header "not constructive" and has been discussed here many times before. "Favorite" doesn't matter all that much here.

Comment: I am asking "Where do I find a site that provides public domain audio files in several known formats that I am allowed to link directly to for testing audio questions at StackOverflow" Where is the problem in this??? Now it is just being closed again by readers of this post to prove a point... Why?

Comment: "Site A does that", "How about site B", "Did you try site C and D?", "Site E would be good", "I use site F and it serves me well". <--- List of answers, no clear "good/correct answer". Close to a poll. Not constructive as a result.

Comment: To add to Bart's answer, it would also become "too localized" as those sites are potentially going to close down at some point, new, better ones may open up, urls could be moved, etc.  Maintaining such lists over time to account for the changes becomes a significant resource drain on SO users.

Comment: And where is the answer with even ONE site? With my attendance and rep, do you not think it likely I would delete or modify the question and answer if the site changed? How long has jsfiddle been active? GitHub ? JSBin ? That is the kind of site I am looking for, not a list of favourites, just one friggin site!