# Why is a question about setting up a php framework using a php package manager off-topic for programming?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, site-recommendation

Why is a question about setting up a PHP framework using a PHP package manager off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Is there a Stack Exchange site where [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940140/can-i-install-laravel-4-without-using-composer) would be considered on-topic?

Comment: To me that seems like an installation issue rather than a programming issue. Perhaps Super User would be better? Have a read through their FAQ first though. I don't participate there, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Unless you are a PHP programmer you would have no use for a php package/dependency manager?

Comment: I would admittedly not have gone for that one all that quickly. But I'm guessing that was the angle they were coming from. Those more active in the PHP tag will have a better idea what is generally done with those questions. So just a comment for now.

Comment: `Composer` tag has 67 followers, and `Laravel` tags have over 500 followers...  Also `git`-related tags have thousands of followers and that is about as related to programming as the question mentioned above.

Comment: I think Off-Topic would fit quite well, if there wouldn't be [that third point which spits in the soup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113087/software-tools-in-faq-is-too-hazy).

Comment: see also: [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773)

Comment: Also, the accepted answer does not address *any* of the questions stated in the question...which seems like a smell that there's something wrong with the question (or bad eye-sight on my end).

Comment: it was answered in the comments of the answer

Comment: I don't care to have it re-opened or anything, I got my answer. I just want to know how it is off-topic? especially if `git`-related questions are not off-topic and there is no other SE site where it fits.

Comment: @decker: That's another smell. Comments are lower-class citizens which are forced to slavery and to live in slums! They're subject to unheralded deletions at all time! ***Important information goes into the answer.***

Comment: i removed my acceptance until he edits the answer :P

Comment: @decker, If it helps, I downvoted your question after the initial posting. "I'd like to know if I can install Laravel 4 without using Composer?" is shotgunning the topic. IMO (not that it matters) questions on SO aren't meant to be edited 10 times to get them just right. You should have all that information up front and ready for potential members to answer. Downvote changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't off topic for Stack Overflow.

[The last revision of the question before it was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15940140/6) doesn't tell me anything about the question that would put it outside the topical scope.

[The original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15940140/1) would probably have been closed as not a real question, but you put in substantial effort into making it a real question that seems to me that it can stay open as such, plus you did so *many hours* before it even got closed. But I just don't see how your question could have *ever* been "off topic", especially considering the reasons you state here.