# Can I ask for additional information about a feature in a Microsoft's technology on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

I want to know additional information about a tool in MS Dynamics AX. But I know I can't ask such questions on Stack Overflow without being humiliated and attacked, lol. I want to know what was the release-date of the feature: Security Development Tool

I don't know where to ask this question.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Include your question in this question and we might be able to tell you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, questions about tools commonly used by developers are on topic, but that doesn't mean every question about those tools are on-topic.  The question still needs to be

- Well researched
- Practically answerable
- Prospective answers should not based on opinions
- Not a long winded discussion
- Not asking for a recommendation or just a link
- And while this isn't directly mentioned in the help center, the answer needs to be useful for other people in the future (or to put it in different terms. it should be somewhat timeless, or at least to the extent that technology can be timeless)

So as long as the question fits within those guidelines, it is usually an acceptable question, however, it is difficult to judge without knowing the specific question.

In your case, you mentioned that you are interested in the release date of specific feature of MS Dynamics AX.  A question like that is not going to be received well and will usually get downvoted and/or closed.

The primary reasoning is 2 part

1. If the feature is real and if the release date has been announced, the information should be readily available so by asking, you would have failed to do your research first.
2. If the feature is still conceptual or the release date hasn't been announced, then the question is not practically answerable and any answers would only be guesses.

Additionally, the question would have limited future value (it won't be timeless) because once the tool is release, the question would have almost zero value.

These types of questions are better directed to other forums on the internet that are better equipped to deal with these types of discussion and opinionated questions.

But if you are looking for a Stack Exchange resource, then you might try [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is a tool used by a developer for software development, so why not.  The exact set of topic allowed on Stack Overflow is identified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That FAQ point is, unfortunately, hazy at best, misleading at worst. It *completely* depends on what question is going to be asked.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby - The FAQ says: *If your question generally covers ... software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!*  What's ambiguous about MS Dynamix AX being such a tool, and a question about it being on topic on SO?

Comment: @JirkaHanika it is ambigious because questions about development tools are on-topic but not **all** questions about such tools really fit the scope of the site.  It is important to understand the exact question before saying on-topic or off-topic to a general idea.

Comment: @JirkaHanika: Should have provided that link earlier: [“Software tools” in FAQ is too hazy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113087/software-tools-in-faq-is-too-hazy)

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby - I agree with the top two answers to the question you linked, both of which say that software development tools are simply on topic.  I do realize that a question may have fatal flaws even while being on topic - maybe that's what you wanted to say.